# ghc-pkg check haddock warnings

Tags: haskell, cabal, haddock

Upon a fresh install of the haskell-platform (via `homebrew`) (`GHC x64 7.6.3`) on `OSX 10.9.2` I receive the following warnings when I run `ghc-pkg check` (see below)

```
Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Users/user/.cabal/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.6.3/ghc-mod-3.1.7/html/ghc-mod.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: /Users/user/.cabal/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.6.3/ghc-mod-3.1.7/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Users/user/.cabal/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.6.3/hlint-1.8.59/html/hlint.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: /Users/user/.cabal/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.6.3/hlint-1.8.59/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: haddock-html: /usr/local/Cellar/haskell-platform/2013.2.0.0/share/doc/mtl-2.1.2/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: haddock-interfaces: /usr/local/Cellar/haskell-platform/2013.2.0.0/share/doc/transformers-0.3.0.0/html/transformers.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: /usr/local/Cellar/haskell-platform/2013.2.0.0/share/doc/transformers-0.3.0.0/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: haddock-interfaces: /usr/local/Cellar/haskell-platform/2013.2.0.0/share/doc/case-insensitive-1.0.0.1/html/case-insensitive.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: /usr/local/Cellar/haskell-platform/2013.2.0.0/share/doc/case-insensitive-1.0.0.1/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
```

Per the docs:

```
ghc-pkg check
    Check the consistency of package depenencies and list broken packages.
    Accepts the --simple-output flag.
```

I attempt to run the following command to generate haddock documentation to no avail:

```
sudo cabal install --reinstall --force-reinstalls --enable-documentation
```

The command was from a similar question a user had on the haskell mailing list.
http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2012-February/021780.html

How do I appease `ghc-pkg check` and remove these warnings?

**CAVEAT**: When I say "fresh install" I mean I have installed the Haskell-platform from scratch, and installed globally `cabal-1.18.0.3`and added cabal's bin directory to my path.

Comment: The warnings complain about `ghc-mod` and `hlint`. Neither are in the Haskell Platform. So if you really did a fresh install of the Haskell Platform, you probably still have old packages in your `~/.cabal` directory from a previous installation.

Comment: There are a *lot* more than just those two, let me paste an update. See above.

Comment: I'm having the exact same thing on Ubuntu (12.04.4 LTS), where I have first uninstalled every Haskell-related package, and then installed the haskell-platform package (2012.1.0.0~debian1).  No .cabal folder in my home directory.  It complains about stm-2.4.2, Cabal-1.18.1.3, and a lot more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those haddock warnings are annoying, but they don't cause any problems, AFAIK. I think the warnings were fixed in Cabal 1.18. I don't see them any more.

---

EDIT: OK, so we need to follow kosmikus's suggestion...

```
mv ~/.cabal ~/.cabal.SAVE
cabal update
```

This will create the file ~/.cabal/config. You can edit this file if you wish.

Now try building something and see if the problem is gone.

Comment: I am using `Cabal-1.18.0.3` (the latest)

Comment: In my specific case (on Ubuntu, see my comment on the question) I have no local .cabal folder.  The cabal version that is part of my haskell-platform is cabal-install 0.14.0 / library 1.14.0.

Comment: Does the directory `/Users/user/.cabal` exist? Is your username `user`?

Comment: I no longer use the Haskell Platform since it's dated, I install it from prebuilt binaries.